# run a task before compile project with gradle automatically

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I wrote a task in a gradle android studio and I want to run my task automatically before project builds running.
is it Possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dependsOn` method.

Something like:

```
task myTask << {
    println 'do it before build'
}

build.dependsOn myTask
```

Comment: I keep getting `Could not get unknown property 'build' for root project`